# LLVM profiling on child process

Tags: apache, clang, profiling, llvm

I want to extract execution traces (e.g., visited basic blocks) when testing [Apache server (httpd)](https://github.com/apache/httpd). Since my work is based on LLVM infrastructure, I choose to use [clang instrumentation based profiling](https://releases.llvm.org/10.0.0/tools/clang/docs/UsersManual.html#profiling-with-instrumentation) as follows:

```
clang -fprofile-instr-generate ${options to compile httpd} -o httpd
export LLVM_PROFILE_FILE=code-%p.profraw
sudo -E ./httpd -k start # output a .profraw
curl ${url} # send a request
sudo -E ./httpd -k stop # output another .profraw
```

The compilation of instrumented httpd works well.
However, I want to track httpd's request handling which is executed in a separate child process. The output .profraw does not record any execution from child processes. As a result, I can only access the execution traces of starting and closing the server. How can I get the .profraw including request handling?

Not restricted in clang profiling. Any solution compatible with LLVM is great. Thanks!

**Update**
From the logs, it turns out the child process whose owner is "daemon" has no write permission to the files

```
LLVM Profile Error: Failed to write file "code-94752.profraw": Permission denied
```

**Problem solved**
The problem is the collision of prof file names. The process `httpd -k start` create multiple child processes as workers. When using `LLVM_PROFILE_FILE=code-%p.profraw`, their pid `%p` is same. So the main process is owned by root and creates the prof file first. Then latter process owned by daemon cannot write that file.

Solution: Use `LLVM_PROFILE_FILE=code-%9m.profraw` (%Nm instead of %p) to avoid name collisions.

Comment: What binary file is executed as child process, is it same httpd binary or some other executable file? For clang profiling the binary should be built with `-fprofile-instr-generate` and `LLVM_PROFILE_FILE` environment variable should be set. Did apache keep the env var for child? Add %p part to this env var when several processes can be profiled.

Comment: Znang, it is great that you was able to find the solution. Could you please repeate which FILE value was working for you? Could you also describe the problem and solution as answer to this question.